# Node.js serve two AngularJS projects in a single solution

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am doing a MEAN application for which there are two modules.

1. visitors
2. admin area

I would like to do the above two area in two separate AngularJS projects since both of them differ a lot in functionality and design. Here is my directory structure.

[image: Directory structure]

But the issue is that when I use both lines of code in following

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/frontend/app')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/admin/app')));
```

it won't work.

Here is my routing

```
app.get('/admin/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./client/admin/app/index.html'); 
});
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./client/frontend/app/index.html'); 
});
```

How can I do the same?

My last option is to put both the index files in the same directory with a different name. Other than that is there any other option?

Comment: Use `res.sendFile(__dirname+'/client/admin/app/index.html');`

Comment: @mukesh will try and update you soon

Comment: @mukesh i tried.It is not working

Comment: is your app worked fine?how?

Comment: yes I implemented same on more projects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have e.g. normal app in `/` and admin app in `/admin`:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/frontend/app')));
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/admin/app')));
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: only the first route is  working.For the second route index file is rendered but the other files are not delivering.

Comment: it was due to i forgot to set the base href in admin tab